# Windows api for locking a file

Tags: fileapi

When we open a word or an excel  file. It gets exclusive lock, so if somebody tries to edit and save the changes, he gets an error stating "file is already used by some other user", he only has the read-only copy of that document which is created in temp folder. So can somebody tell me which api is used by windows for locking a file on open.

Answer (score 0):

See dwShareMode param from [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) API. Can give you the file or device cannot shared or not opened until the handle to the file or device is closed. Also see [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx).